# How to prevent "stale element" inside a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using `Selenium` for retrieve data from this [site,](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/paok-spartak-moscow-pIXFEt8o/#ah;2) and I encountered a little problem when I try to click an element within a `foreach`.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to get the table associated to a specific category of odds, in the link above we have different categories:

[image]

As you can see from the image, I clicked on `Asian handicap -1.75` and the site has generated a table through javascript, so inside my code I'm trying to get that table finding the corresponding element and clicking it.

**Code**

Actually I have two methods, the first called `GetAsianHandicap` which iterate over all categories of odds:

```
public List<T> GetAsianHandicap(Uri fixtureLink)
{ 
    //Contains all the categories displayed on the page
    string[] categories = new string[] { "-1.75", "-1.5", "-1.25", "-1", "-0.75", "-0.5", "-0.25", "0", "+0.25", "+0.5", "+0.75", "+1", "+1.25", "+1.5", "+1.75" };

    foreach(string cat in categories)
    {
        //Get the html of the table for the current category
        string html = GetSelector("Asian handicap " + asian);

        if(html == string.Empty)
            continue;

        //other code
    }
}
```

and then the method `GetSelector` which click on the searched element, this is the design:

```
public string GetSelector(string selector)
{
    //Get the available table container (the category). 
    var containers = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='table-container']"));

    //Store the html to return.
    string html = string.Empty;

    foreach (IWebElement container in containers)
    {
       //Container not available for click.
       if (container.GetAttribute("style") == "display: none;")
            continue;

       //Get container header (contains the description).
       IWebElement header = container.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[starts-with(@class, 'table-header')]"));

       //Store the table description.
       string description = header.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Text;

       //The container contains the searched category
       if (description.Trim() == selector)
       {
           //Get the available links.
           var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table")).FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

           //Get the element to click.
           IWebElement element = listItems.Where(li => li.Text == selector).FirstOrDefault();

           //The element exist
           if (element != null)
           {
               //Click on the container for load the table.
               element.Click();

               //Wait few seconds on ChromeDriver for table loading.
               driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

               //Get the new html of the page
               html = driver.PageSource;
           }

           return html;
       }

       return string.Empty;
    }
```

**Problem and exception details**

When the `foreach` reach this line:

```
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table")).FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

I get this exception:

> 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException' in WebDriver.dll
>   stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Searching for the error means that the html page source was changed, but in this case I store the element to click in a variable and the html itself in another variable, so I can't get rid to patch this issue.

Someone could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain with words what you are trying to do. 1. Navigate to the site, 2. Find each handicap link in the table and click it, 3. ??? Get the odds from the table that opens when #2 is clicked? I'm confused. There's a much simpler way to do all this but I need more info first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your code and I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. I'm assuming you want to scrape the table that is exposed when you click one of the handicap links. Here's some simple code to do this. It dumps the text of the elements which ends up unformatted but you can use this as a starting point and add functionality if you want. I didn't run into any StaleElementExceptions when running this code and I never saw the page refresh so I'm not sure what other people were seeing.

```
string url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/paok-spartak-moscow-pIXFEt8o/#ah;2";
driver.Url = url;

// get all the (visible) handicap links and click them to open the page and display the table with odds
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Asian handicap')]")).Where(e => e.Displayed).ToList();
foreach (var link in links)
{
    link.Click();
}

// print all the odds tables
foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='table-container']")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("====================================");
}
```

I would suggest that you spend some more time learning locators. Locators are very powerful and can save you having to stack nested loops looking for one thing... and then children of that thing... and then children of that thing... and so on. The right locator can find all that in one scrape of the page which saves a lot of code and time.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in related [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748839/how-to-prevent-page-refresh), this issue is because site executes an auto refresh.

> Solution 1:

I would suggest if there is an explicit way to do refresh, perform that refresh on a periodic basis, or (if you are sure, when you need to do refresh).

> Solution 2:

Create a Extension method for `FindElement` and `FindElements`, so that it try to get element for a given timeout.

```
public static void FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout)
{
   if(timeout >0)
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(by));
    }

 return driver.FindElement(by);
}

 public static IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout)
{
   if(timeout >0)
    {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
    }

 return driver.FindElements(by);
}
```

so your code will use these like this:

```
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table"), 30).FindElements(By.TagName("a"),30);
```

> Solution 3:

Handle StaleElementException using an Extension Method:

```
public static void FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int maxAttempt)
{
    for(int attempt =0; attempt <maxAttempt; attempt++)
    {
       try
       {
           driver.FindElement(by);
           break;
       }
       catch(StaleElementException)
       {
       }
    }
}

 public static IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElements(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int maxAttempt)
{
  for(int attempt =0; attempt <maxAttempt; attempt++)
    {
       try
       {
            driver.FindElements(by);
           break;
       }
       catch(StaleElementException)
       {
       }
    }
}
```

Your code will use these like this:

```
var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table"), 2).FindElements(By.TagName("a"),2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just a question on the second solution: you declare the method as void but at the same time you used a return, is an error or something?

Comment: It's an extension method, so when you use `driver.`, you will see two overloaded method for `findElement` as well as `FindElements`.

Comment: I'm having some problem on the extension method `FindElements`, in particular this line: `var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table"), 2).FindElements(By.TagName("a"), 2);` says: `No overload of the 'FindElements' method accepts 2 arguments` This is weird because the extension method accept the overload on `FindElement` but not on `FindElements`, any idea of why?

Comment: I have added both extension , for findElement as well as FindElements. Check my answer.

Comment: Yep I saw, I did the same in my code.. that's why I'm confused right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177665/discussion-between-charanoglu-and-raj-kamal).

Comment: In this call i.e. `var listItems = driver.FindElement(By.Id("odds-data-table"), 2).FindElements(By.TagName("a"),2);` , you are not using `driver.FindElements` but it's a `Element.FindElements`. Checkout my answer **EDIT** section.

Comment: I haven't tried the **EDIT** extension, but I think it should work.

Comment: I send you another message in the chat, maybe could you take a look at it?

Comment: Check my message.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
string description = header.FindElement(By.XPath("strong/a")).Text;
```

instead of your:

```
string description = header.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Text;
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem too